# MYSQL DB Normalization & Query Indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-normalization

We currently have a table that contains 90 columns and as the table is growing and the business needs change, we're having to alter the table alot (add/remove cols & indexes).

```
|------ (Table name: quotes)
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
....
|completed_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|reviewed_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|marked_dud_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|closed_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|subscribed_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|admin_checked_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|priced_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|number_verified_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|created_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
|deleted_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
```

For the application, our staff are constantly querying all sorts of variations on the above data, example being where it has been completed (completed_at), checked (admin_checked_at) and not deleted, reviewed (deleted_at, reviewed_at)

We're thinking it may be easier to offload some of these columns into their own row, we'll call it quotes_actions, then when querying do some joining.

```
|------  (Table name: quotes_actions)
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**id**//|int(11)|No|
|quote_id|int(11)|No|
|action|varchar(100)|No|
|user_id|int(11)|No|
|time|datetime|Yes|NULL
|created_at|datetime|Yes|NULL
```

An example would be action = 'completed' using the field, with an index covering quote_id and action.

We've split the data into this format on 150,000 rows and it's not any faster nor slower than querying the original database with correct indexes.

Has anyone got any experience with this and has any recommendations or pitfalls for each approach? It's taking a lot of time to add covering indexes and add columns to the original table as we needed them, whereas the second approach has the indexes set up ready to go but is introducing a lot more joins and more complicated queries.

```
0.09s
select * from `quotes` 
where `completed_at` is not null 
and `approved_at` is not null 
and deleted_at is null
```

=>

```
0.0005s
select * from `quotes_new` 
inner join quotes_actions as q1 on q1.action = 'completed' and q1.quote_id = quotes_new.id
inner join quotes_actions as q2 on q2.action = 'approved' and q2.quote_id = quotes_new.id
where quotes_new.deleted_at is null
```

In addition, if the 2nd approach is better, how do you query for negative results, where a quote hasn't been approved?

Comment: stop all these alterings. Sit down with the team and figure out how to normalize your database.

Comment: Follow the 3 NFs for a normalization of your db instead of forming such awkward solutions

Comment: Not sure if this is really a normalization issue. Your first table doesnt show a normalization issue IMOH. The problem here is more an unmature product being live. Brainstorming with the team may help indeed. But seeing  the number of "quotes_action" columns, and considering that you add more and more of them on a regular basis, for clarity I would go 2nd solution. You can still make some VIEWS to get back your original table layout and faciliate the queries.

Comment: Do you need `DATETIME`?  Or would `DATE` suffice, thereby saving 2 bytes each.

Comment: Are some of these sequential?  As in the important thing is the "state" -- created, then reviewed, then priced, then completed?  If so, you need to record the 'state' as a single ordered number and abandon the dates, perhaps.

Comment: Your option 2 smacks of EAV, which sucks.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same as @RickJames, add a `state` column. You could keep the second table with the log of actions, but only as a sort of audit of what happened and when. Primarily query the `state` column. If the states are not serial like Rick asks, you might have to include funny states like "priced_but_not_reviewed" or other combinations. PS: **don't** use ENUM for the state, because changing the possible states will still require ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Thanks Rich and others - we went with 3 new columns which define the status. We've grouped the different status into 3 groups and hence the 3 state columns with a compound index.

Answer (score 0):

Database design will vary from application to application, and things that are great for one implementation will be terrible for another.  You've identified a few things that are important to you:

- speed of data access (at least no reduction in current performance)
- ability to respond to application needs/changes
- limiting complexity of queries

Without being able to see the entirity of your database and how you are using it, these are the principles I would follow:

### Use Stored Procedures and Views for as much as possible

This is just good design.  You create an adapter layer between your application and the data tables, which allows you to make whatever changes you need to in the database (and the views/stored procs) without having to change the application itself.  Decoupling your systems makes maintenance significantly easier.  Also this is good for security, as if the only way outsiders can access the data is through your stored procs, you've eliminated a few avenues of attack. (There's also debate about whether or not the DBMS will cache execution plans for stored procedures, making them execute faster than similar queries, but I'm not a DBA or DBDev, so I'm not touching that).

### Attempt to limit width of tables

One thing I've seen time and time again is every time a need arises in a production systems, a column gets added to a table and they call it a day.  Far easier than rewriting a bunch of queries or reviewing table structures.  This is terrible design.  If you've already limited the changes needed to the application layer by following my first piece of advice, you've limited the work needed to actually resolve table changes in the right way.  You should always evaluate whether data belongs to the row in question, or if it should be offloaded into its own table.  You shouldn't be afraid to radically alter your database, as sometimes it is necessary.

Looking at the data you've provided, I think your second option is okay.  You've identified many columns that actually represent the same thing (the "status changes" or as you put it "quote actions" that occur) and offloaded that from the main table to a secondary table.  This is perfectly fine, and likely will be effective.  You can further "cheat" to make this table faster by offloading status onto its own table, and using an integer to represent it instead of a string (since the string doesn't matter to the database, and integers are far faster to index and search).

This is not to say a wide table is a bad thing, sometimes tables just need to be wide.  You just need to evaluate whether the data really belongs to the entity the data row represents.

### Approach queries in new ways

You will want to play with the execution plan tools of your DBMS and understand how each query really works.  Changing the order of joins can drastically alter the query return speed, and you shouldn't be afraid to use table variables and temp tables in your queries.  They are all tools at your disposal.

### Querying for Negative Results

Since you asked this question specifically, I'll address it.  This requires thinking about your query in a little different way (consequently, if you haven't, you should look into taking a course or working through a textbook of Relational Algebra, it makes understanding databases so much easier).

Your original query made finding something where the quote was not approved easy.  It was all in the table: approved_at is null.  Simple, easy peasy, no problems.  Now, however, instead of being in a column on the main table, it is in its own table, that also represents all the other actions that could be taken.  You need to break the problem down a little.

You want to find the set wherein of all orders, there is no action to signify it is approved.  In SQL that looks like:

```
 select quote_id from quotes_action where quote_id not in 
           (select quote_id from quotes_action where action = 'approved');
```

### Final Thoughts

You need to sit down with your team and talk about how you want to move forward with this product.  Spend a few days or a couple weeks really thinking deeply about it.  Brainstorm....hackathon....do something to find a solution you like and makes your product better and more maintainable.  We've all been in the situation where we have an unmaintainable product that could have been fixed at some point, but is beyond that point.  Try not to get to that point, and fix it while you have the opportunity.

Comment: I disagree with using stored procs and views "as much as possible" specifically for MySQL, because the implementation of stored procs and views in MySQL is inefficient and hard to develop. It's likely to cause more problems than it solves. This advice may be appropriate for other RDBMS products like Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @BillKarwin Do you have a source on them being inefficient in MySQL?  I've not done stored proc work in MySQL since school.  However, "it's hard to develop" is never a good reason on its own not to do something, especially if it reduces workload later.

Comment: Here's a blog from former MySQL Community Manager Jay Pipes, describing how stored procedures are compiled in MySQL. http://www.joinfu.com/2010/05/mysql-stored-procedures-aint-all-that/

Comment: @BillKarwin looks like some of the issues were cleaned up since then (mentioned in the comments), but, like I mentioned, I'm not getting into a debate about caching, nor recommending stored procs for their performance improvements.  I recommend them for security and maintainability.